# How to get ID or Key from Firebase realtime

Tags: html, database, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this, and what I want to get is the ID or Key from each user.

For example: `WxA2XLigx7V1bOxm5WNSnVkgtOu1`

[image: Firebase image]

And I'm currently showing this so far:

[image: Table database]

This is my current code that shows the table

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/').on('value',(data)=>{

  let Users = data.val();
  document.getElementById('tablaUsers').innerHTML+='';
  for (const user in Users){
    document.getElementById('tablaUsers').innerHTML+=`
    <tr>
    <td>${Users[user].Key}</td>
    <td>${Users[user].email}</td>
    <td>${Users[user].name}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
}
```

And this is the code from the html

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" role="columnheader" scope="col">ID</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" role="columnheader" scope="col">Email</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" role="columnheader" scope="col">Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablaUsers">
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see my

```
<td>${Users[user].Key}</td>
```

Is not working, it's just a placeholder. It may be a simple problem but I can´t get it or how to do it, hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

You should loop on the JavaScript object returned by the [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot?authuser=0#val) method, as follows:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users/')
    .on('value', (data) => {
      var obj = data.val();
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        console.log('key: ' + key);
        console.log('mail: ' + obj[key].mail);
        console.log('name: ' + obj[key].name);
      });
    });
```

Comment: @Locus Hello, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: i'm so sorry to answer so late, had a bunch of projects during the time I asked that question and ended up doing an alternative with Firestore and Realtime Database but your Solution is way more optimal and way less work